# Abp framework - Does not include foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, abp

I have the following data model:

```
Class Person  : Entity<long>
{
    // Id is ABP primary key
    public string name {get;set;}
}

Class Car  : Entity<long>
{
    // Id is ABP primary key
    public long PERSONID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PERSONID")]
    public Person PersonModel { get; set; }
}
```

In dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("IDPERSON");
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasIndex(p => new { p.PERSONID, p.OTHERKEY }).IsUnique();
```

Results in the following tables:

Table person

```
IDPERSON,NAME
```

Table car

```
Id, PERSONID, OTHERKEY
```

**PROBLEM**: when I retrieve a record from the repository `Car` with `Get` or `GetAll`, it does not include the model `Person`.

```
{
    Id: 1,
    PERSONID: 1,
    Person: null
}
```

Notes: records with keys exist in tables

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use Include

```
var car= dbContext.Cars.Include(p=> p.PersonModel).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==carId);
```

or to get all

```
var cars= dbContext.Cars.Include(p=> p.PersonModel).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks. In abp/aspnetboilerplate: var query =  Repository.GetAllIncluding(x=>x.Person)